# How do I integrate vuetify into storybook in a NUXT 3 application?

Tags: storybook, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3, storybook-addon

I have vuetify ^3.1.6 installed and functional in the app
Installed storybook using the command `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type vue3`

My .storybook/preview.js content is as follows

`import { withVuetify } from 'storybook-addon-vuetify3/dist/decorators'`
`export const parameters = {`
`actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },`
`controls: {`
 `matchers: {`
`color: /(background|color)$/i,`
`date: /Date$/,`
`},`
 `}, }`

`export const decorators = [`
 `withVuetify`
`]`

It's my first time working with Nuxt js but i have worked with vue js,

I already tried, using storybook/addon-vuetify3 but i get the error

`ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-2!./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css) Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):`